# Is there a way to rename a function during import?

Tags: python

I have a class like this:

```
# in bar.py
class Bar:
  ...
  @staticmethod
  def foo():
    ...
```

Is there a way to import `Bar.foo` in another python file, but rename it to be called as just `foo`? I have tried `import bar`, `from bar import Bar` but none of those work.

Comment: One option: `import bar` `foo = bar.Bar.foo`

Answer (score 1):

You could just do

```
from bar import Bar
foo = Bar.foo
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to do these aliases? There are quite a number of functions in `Bar` that I'd like to import

Comment: I would recommend you just import the class and call `Bar.foo()` etc.

Comment: @JRR have you considered not using a bunch of static methods, and just using module-level functions? Otherwise, just use `Bar.foo()`

Comment: @JRR you can't import members of an object in any language, just use the object itself or move the function outside of class(they anyway are static) and then import them as you wish

Answer (score 0):

> from bar.Bar import foo as bar_Bar_foo

especially useful when you need both `requests` the module and `Flask.requests` in the same file, so to avoid a collision:

```
from Flask import requests as f_requests
import requests
```

Comment: Bar is in its own file bar.py. so this doesn't work I thought?

Comment: You can't import a method from a class. I get `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: edited - `from _filename_ import _classname_` or even `from _filename_._classname_ import _method_`, but not sure the latter would work